# How can I disable clear button in react-native-signature-canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native-signature-canvas for drawing the signatures. It's working fine but now I want to disable the 'clear' button provided by the library. I have gone through the docs, but I haven't found any prop or method to do it. Any workaround or lead?

```
                 <Signature
                  onOK={(img) => {
                    const { signatureCount } = this.state;
                    if (signatureCount < 1) {
                      this.setState({ signature: img }, () => {
                        utils.showToast("Signature Saved");
                      });
                      this.setState({ signatureCount: 1 });
                    } else {
                      utils.showToast("Signature can't be save more than once");
                    }
                  }}
                  ref={this.signatureRef}
                  bgWidth={imgWidth}
                  bgHeight={imgHeight}
                  clearText="Clear"
                  confirmText="Save"
                  onBegin={() => this.setState({ scroll: false })}
                  onEnd={() => this.setState({ scroll: true })}
                  webStyle={style}
                  imageType="image/png"
                  onClear={() => {
                    this.signatureRef.current.redo();
                  }}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
webStyle = `.m-signature-pad {box-shadow: none; border: none;.m-signature-pad--body {border: none;}.m-signature-pad--footer {display: none; margin: 0px;}body,html {width: 100px; height: 100px;}`